# Kivy opening bubble with button

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I want to be able to open the bubble with a button click.
I am kind of new to kivy.
Here's the code in the kivy file:

```
  Button:
        bubble:bubble.__self__
        text:"Home"
        on_release:self.show_bubble
        Bubble:
            id:bubble       
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: (150, 50)        
            pos_hint: {'x': 1, 'y': 1.7}    
            arrow_pos: 'bottom_mid'        
            orientation: 'horizontal'       
            BubbleButton:            
                text: "This is"        
            BubbleButton:            
                text: "a"        
            BubbleButton:            
                text: "Bubble"
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide all code (Pastebin), please.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have worked in KIVY for mobile-based application development. But let me tell you its quite a pain. If you just want to make interactive python programs that are not mobile based I think you should start with the Tkinter module.

KIVY is really ugly. I suggest porting to JAVA for mobile application development simply because it was born to do that.

We have a long way till everyone starts using python for mobile apps.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It does nothing to address the question and just goes off-topic.

Comment: If the OP asks something you do not want to answer, do not answer in the first place, this is mere spam!

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the example shown here:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.bubble.html

i.e. put the `Bubble` in a separate `FloatLayout` (for example) instead of inside the triggering `Button`